# Как работает GtkRevealer?

Tags: c, gtk3, gtk+, glade

Как я понял это аналог `gtk_widget_hide` и `gtk_widget_show`, только скрывает или показывает он свой дочерний виджет с анимацией.

У меня есть виджет `GtkRevealer` в котором находится кнопка,  с помощью функции `gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child(GTK_REVEALER(Revealer),FALSE);` я пытаюсь скрыть кнопку, но ничего не выходит, что я не понял?

Версия Gtk 3.24.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*GtkRevealer* это контейнер который может содержать одного потомка и скрывать его или отображать с анимацией.

метод  `gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child()` скрывает или отображает потомка.

Но вначале нужно настроить как должен быть анимирована переход с использованем метода 
`gtk_revealer_set_transition_type()`

также в [Theming in GTK](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html) должна быть настроена анимация при переходе

также должна быть открыта анимация в GtkSettings свойство `gtk-enable-animations`
эти свойства устанавливаются через метод

```
    g_object_set(gtk_object, "gtk-enable-animation", 1, NULL);
```

Comment: Но это работает!

Answer (score 2):

> Как работает GtkRevealer

[image: GTK]

Пример:

```
extern crate gtk;
use gtk::*;

fn main() {
    if gtk::init().is_err() {
        eprintln!("failed to initialize GTK Application");
        std::process::exit(1);
    }

    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);
    window.set_default_size(400, 200);

    let header = HeaderBar::new();
    header.set_show_close_button(true);
    header.set_title("App");

    window.set_titlebar(&header);

    let vbox = Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 0);
    window.add(&vbox);

    let revealer = Revealer::new();
    revealer.set_transition_type(RevealerTransitionType::SlideRight);
    revealer.set_transition_duration(2000);

    let label_1 = Label::new("Test label");
    revealer.add(&label_1);

    let btn = Button::new_with_label("Show/Hide");
    let revealer_1 = revealer.clone();
    btn.connect_clicked(move |_| {
        let cur = revealer_1.get_reveal_child();
        println!("{:?}", cur);
        revealer_1.set_reveal_child(!cur);
    });

    vbox.pack_start(&btn, true, true, 0);
    vbox.pack_end(&revealer, true, true, 0);

    window.show_all();
    gtk::main();
}
```

Comment: Так что же делает `gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child`?

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич смотря на каком уровне понимания Вы хотите с этим разобраться... Формально вот: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRevealer.html#gtk-revealer-set-reveal-child

Comment: исходя из вопроса можно было понять что доки я чекал

Comment: Спасибо конечно за пример кода(хоть в тегах написан язык Си, а не С++,если это вообще С++),но вы так и не объяснили что делает `gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child`. Прочитайте мой вопрос, а не заголовок.